# RewriteRule with Query_String

Tags: redirects, query-string

I have

```
http//royatlon.north.com/cybersource/fp/clear.png?org_id=1snn5n9w&amp;session_id=sterling40272003&amp;m=1
```

and I would like to rewrite it to this:

```
https://media.north.com/fp/clear.png?org_id=1snn5n9w&amp;session_id=sterling40272003&amp;m=1
```

How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cybersource/fp/clear.png/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}^(.*)org_id=1snn5n9w&amp;session_id=sterling40272003&amp;m=1(&.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule^(.*)$ https://media.north.com/fp/clear.pngorg_id=1snn5n9w&amp;session_id=sterling40272003&amp;m=1 [R=301,L]
```

...but it's not working.

---

But here is the problem, I have multiple URLs for one host for example I have this:

### If the request is

`http//royatlon.north.com/cybersource/fp/clear.png?org_id=1snn5n9w&session_id=sterling40272003&m=1`
**rewrite it to**
`https://media.north.com/fp/clear.png?org_id=1snn5n9w&session_id=sterling40272003&m=1`

### If the request is

`http//royatlon.north.com/cybersource/fp/clear.png?org_id=1snn5n9w&session_id=sterling40272003&m=2`
**rewrite it to**
`https://media.north.com/fp/clear.png?org_id=1snn5n9w&session_id=sterling40272003&m=2`

Comment: Presumably you mean _external_ redirect, rather than an _internal_ rewrite? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried this out

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cybersource/fp/clear.png/

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)org_id=1snn5n9w&amp;session_id=sterling40272003&amp;m=1(&.*)$ [NC]

Comment: You can edit your question to include this additional information, rather than commenting.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://media.north.com/fp/clear.png?org_id=1snn5n9w&amp;session_id=sterling40272003&amp;m=1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 3):

I think you're reasonably close. However, `&` (ampersands) are not HTML encoded in the request, so you should check just for `&` and not `&amp;`. Special HTML characters should only be HTML encoded in your source HTML document.

I think the few omitted spaces (argument delimiters) are perhaps just due to the copy/paste of your code?

Try this (in .htaccess - I assume):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*org_id=1snn5n9w&session_id=sterling40272003&m=1(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^cybersource/fp/clear.png$ https://media.north.com/fp/clear.png?org_id=1snn5n9w&session_id=sterling40272003&m=1 [R=301,L]
```

It looks a bit strange that you would be matching against the `session_id`, since the *session id* is usually something which changes often and is potentially a bit random - but I assume that is required?

This also checks for optional characters before and after your source query string, as hinted at by your code, although this isn't specifically stated in your original question.

If `royatlon.north.com` and `media.north.com` are served from the same place then you may need to also include a `RewriteCond` directive for the `HTTP_HOST`.

---

**EDIT:** In view of your recent edit, I think AgA's solution (mod_alias) is perhaps preferable, however, in keeping with mod_rewrite and assuming you do need to *match* the exact query string and not simply pass it through, then...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^org_id=1snn5n9w&session_id=sterling40272003&m=\d$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^cybersource/fp/clear.png$ https://media.north.com/fp/clear.png [R=301,L]
```

This matches a single digit (`\d`) at the end of the query string and the same query string is then passed through to the target.

Answer (score 2):

Pl. try this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/royatlon.north.com/cybersource/(.*) https://media.north.com/$1
```

Comment: did not work out, i don't know where am i making mistake at

Comment: It should be `RedirectMatch`. I think this is perhaps the better solution, providing you don't need any more fine grained control on the pattern match. (+1)

Comment: @raj I've corrected it as per w3d's advice.